# Elasticsearch Multi-Term Auto Completion

Tags: elasticsearch, search, autocomplete, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to implement the Multi-Term Auto Completion that's presented [here](https://project-a.github.io/on-site-search-design-patterns-for-e-commerce/#multi-term-auto-completion).

Filtering down to the correct documents works, but when aggregating the `completion_terms` they are not filtered to those that match the current partial query, but instead include all `completion_terms` from any matched documents.

Here are the mappings:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic" : "false",
    "properties" : {
      "completion_ngrams" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "analyzer" : "completion_ngram_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer" : "completion_ngram_search_analyzer"
      },
      "completion_terms" : {
        "type" : "keyword",
        "normalizer" : "completion_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the settings:

```
{
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "analysis" : {
          "filter" : {
            "edge_ngram" : {
              "type" : "edge_ngram",
              "min_gram" : "1",
              "max_gram" : "10"
            }
          },
          "normalizer" : {
            "completion_normalizer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "german_normalization"
              ],
              "type" : "custom"
            }
          },
          "analyzer" : {
            "completion_ngram_search_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            },
            "completion_ngram_analyzer" : {
              "filter" : [
                "lowercase",
                "edge_ngram"
              ],
              "tokenizer" : "whitespace"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm then indexing data like this:

```
{
  "completion_terms" : ["Hammer", "Fortis", "Tool", "2000"],
  "completion_ngrams": "Hammer Fortis Tool 2000"
}
```

Finally, the autocomplete search looks like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "fortis"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "hammer"
          }
        },        
        {
          "match": {
            "completion_ngrams": "too"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "autocomplete": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "completion_terms",
        "size": 100
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This correctly returns documents matching the search string "fortis hammer too", but the aggregations include ALL completion terms that are included in any of the matched documents, e.g. for the query above:

```
"buckets": [
  { "key": "fortis" },
  { "key": "hammer" },
  { "key": "tool" },
  { "key": "2000" },
]
```

Ideally, I'd expect

```
"buckets": [
  { "key": "tool" }
]
```

I could filter out the terms that are already covered by the search query ("fortis" and "hammer" in this case) in the app, but the "2000" doesn't make any sense from a user's perspective, because it doesn't partially match any of the provided search terms.

I understand why this is happening, but I can't think of a solution. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

try `filters agg` please

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "fortis"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "hammer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "completion_ngrams": "too"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "findOuthammerAndfortis": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "fortis": {
            "term": {
              "completion_terms": "fortis"
            }
          },
          "hammer": {
            "term": {
              "completion_terms": "hammer"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This does filter the results, but it no longer gives me the suggestions I need. It just returns the document count, e.g. `{ "buckets": { "fortis": { "doc_count": 20 } } }`. Not sure if I missed something, I'm relatively new to elasticsearch.

Comment: terms agg and filters agg both only return the doc_count，whant else do you need

Comment: The difference is that the terms aggregate gives me the `doc_count` and the corresponding `key`, whereas with the filters aggregate I need to set the keys I want to receive myself. The purpose behind this is to use the keys returned in the aggregate as search suggestions, so it doesn't make sense if I have to specify them myself. However, I only want to receive suggestions that match the partial search term, "too" in this case.

Comment: it’s not clear, which of the following do you want or what else?
1. get all groups `key`?  then use terms agg
2.get some `key` you want? then you must filter out them

Comment: {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "fortis"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "completion_terms": "hammer"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "completion_ngrams": "too"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "findOuthammerAndfortis": {
      "filters": {
        "filters": {
          "too": {
            "term": {
              "completion_terms": "too"
            }
          }
        }
      }}}}

Comment: I want to get the autocomplete functionality that's described in the link above. They describe that they query on an array field with keywords and an edge_ngram field for partial matches. Then they aggregate the results on the array field to get search suggestions for the current search term.
I'm not sure how that should work though, espcially with the short aggregate query they share in the link. The difference to just using the elastic completion field is that the method described is able to combine known terms in an arbitrary order.